# PhpStorm won't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

Not sure what happened, PhpStorm IDE just isn't starting. I click on the Favorites icon and nothing happens. Program simply doesn't start.

I've tried reinstalling it like it says here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-and-launching.html#install-on-linux-with-snaps

But terminal says:

```
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic

error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/phpstorm: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused


● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-06-19 07:00:10 EDT; 6s ago
  Process: 9826 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9826 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 07:00:10 jUbuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
```

I'm at a complete loss here, incredibly confused. I just want PHP Storm to work.

Comment: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) would probably be a better place to ask. Although PhpStorm is a programming tool, this looks like a more generic systemd or snapd problem.

Comment: try with tool box: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/